# Flutter : tflite_flutter run on iPhone in debug mode but not in release mode

Tags: flutter, tensorflow, face-recognition, face-detection, tflite

I have a running application using which I can recognize faces.
In that, **.tflite** model is working perfectly on Android.

I am facing issues on iOS, in which the application is perfectly running in debug mode, but it is not working in release mode.

Refer to the following code snippet:

```
Future loadModel() async {
    final options = InterpreterOptions();
    tempDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();

    print("load");
    try {
      options.addDelegate(GpuDelegate());
      interpreter = await tfl.Interpreter.fromAsset('mobilefacenet.tflite',
          options: options);
      setState(() {
        faceModel = "loaded successfully";
      });
    } on Exception {
      setState(() {
        faceModel = "failed to load";
      });
      print('Failed to load model.');
    }
  }
```

ERROR Return:

```
Unhandled Exception: Invalid argument(s): Failed to lookup symbol 'TFLGpuDelegateCreate': dlsym(RTLD_DEFAULT, TFLGpuDelegateCreate):
```

The above code is running perfectly on iPhone in Debug mode, but when running it using **flutter run --release**, the command app is not loading the **tflite** model.

Comment: I have a simular issue: my app is running perfectly on Android and iOS with flutter run, but stops working when I upload it to Apple's App Store. Have you found any solution to this?